# how to retrieve the values in [object Object] javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have this on my backend:

```
 app.get('/dashboard', async(req, res) => {
  
  const customers = await stripe.customers.list();

  customers.data.forEach(customer => {
    // console.log(customer.metadata);
  });

  res.render('dashboard.ejs', {customer: customers})
  console.log(customers)

})
```

and on my front-end (ejs):

```
  <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>NAME</th>
        <th>EMAIL</th>
        <th>ACTIONS</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <% if(customer.data.length){ 
        for(var i = 0;i < customer.data.length;i++) { %>
      <tr>
          <script>
              let kk = JSON.stringify('<%=customer.data%>')
              console.log(kk)
          </script>
      <td><%=customer.data%></td>
         <% }
        }else{ %>
            <p>err</p>
        <% } %>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

but when I log `kk`, it returns `[object Object]`, and the same when I put it out to the screen, as you can see I am doing above. How can I fix this?

Comment: its  because ```kk``` isn't ```[Object Object]``` notice the difference. It shows that your current ```kk``` is not only an object but a combination of an Object and and something else.

Comment: try doing ```console.log(Object.enteries(kk))``` and analyze the output.

Comment: @seriously so im a little bit confused on why it is putting it out like that to the screen then too. also, when i did the `Object.entries` log, it returned over 160 lines that looked like `["3", "b"] `

Comment: 160 lines is probably because it is calling it repetedly to check for updates thats fine. You now have to annalye what ```<%=customer.data%>``` contains and what kind of data it is (i.e is it an object, an array, a string... in order to decide how to handle it on front end. Try loging it on server side before sending it to client side to determine the data type

Comment: got it. see i did log it on my server-side, and when i do, it returns everything i need, but then passing it through to the front end, it displays it as object Object. So i'm wondering if i am trying to access customer.data wrong in the first place. I need the `customer.data.metadata`, so trying to access the data part first :(

Comment: I think the problem might be from the way you are sending the data on the server side. Try wrapping the data you are send in braces like ```{ variable_containing_data }``` and log it on client side and analayze it. Is it still  returning```[object Object} ?

Comment: actuslly not returning anything now.

Comment: did you add the ```{ }``` on serverside or client side

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239179/discussion-between-gianlps-and-seriously).

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
Object.keys(kk)
```

to get the keys of the object and then access values using the keys.

more complete answer

```
for key in Object.keys(kk) {
   value = kk[key];
   console.log(value);
}
```

you can also use `JSON.stringify(kk)`

Comment: i appreciate your answer, but it doens't really help me access the data inside the object Object.

Comment: you can call the function recursivly